# Join string in LINQ 2 Entity

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

I would like to join string (at SQL server side) in LINQ 2 Entity.

Is it even possible given the fact that LINQ 2 Entity can't translate the Aggregate function?

(btw, I just don't understand why L2S supports the Aggregate function but LINQ 2 Entity doesn't)

I tried to generate an expression tree to do this, and this is what I came up with:

```
ParameterExpression list = Expression.Parameter(typeof(List<string>), "list");
ParameterExpression i = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "i");
ParameterExpression result = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "r");

LabelTarget label = Expression.Label(typeof(string));

BlockExpression block = Expression.Block
(
    new[] { i, result },
    Expression.Assign(result, Expression.Property(list, "Item", Expression.Constant(0))),
    Expression.Assign(i, Expression.Constant(0)),
    Expression.Loop
    (
        Expression.IfThenElse
        (
            Expression.LessThan
            (
                Expression.PreIncrementAssign(i),
                Expression.Property(list, "Count")
            ),
            Expression.Assign
            (
                result,
                Expression.Call
                (
                    null,
                    typeof(string).GetMethod
                    (
                        "Concat",
                        new Type[]
                        {
                            typeof(string),
                            typeof(string),
                            typeof(string)
                        }
                    ),
                    new Expression[]
                    {
                        result,
                        Expression.Constant(","),
                        Expression.Property(list, "Item", i)
                    }
                )
            ),
            Expression.Break(label, result)
        ),
        label
    )
);

var join = Expression.Lambda<Func<List<string>, string>>(block, list);

Response.Write(join.Compile()(new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" }));
```

This is working good for `List<string>`, I get the result "a,b,c".

But I can't figure out how to apply this code to `IQueryable<string>`.

The `IQueryable<string>` doesn't have the "Item" property, and even there is a way to get an element by index on IQueryable, how does this translate to SQL?

So, is there any way to accomplish the join string task (at SQL server side) in LINQ 2 Entity?

Comment: Why are you keen on doing the join server side? I think you're asking for trouble, to be honest.

Comment: Yes, of course it's not the only way to achieve the task at hand, but it's the most straight forward logic in my task. And I'm just curious to know if it's possible.